# What are the way to avoid http service error in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, performance, http, httpwebrequest

In my project used quick search for character based send request to server , But on time the user fastly type then i got http service error So i want to know how avoid that problem or any possiable to avoid continue request to server or any message queue technical for that problem . kindly give suggestion it's helpful to all

Comment: is it really necessary to send every input to the server? Expect how many HTTPServices you would send if a lot of people would use this search or whatever.

Comment: no need to send everyinput to the sever but i want to characher search based on name ,

Answer (score 0):

If there is a typing delay greater that X milliseconds (e.g. 500), send the request.

Comment: What would be if the request need more than X (e.g.500) ms to get a result? I think there should be another way to solve the problem.